# Switching active display in windows

Tags: windows-10

I have 2 monitors, left one for fullscreen browser and right one for fullscreen ide. Is there any keyboard shortcut or tool which lets me switch the active display? I mean I was coding in my ide, now suddenly I want to search something so I switch my active display left, open a new tab and start searching.

Comment: Unfortunately the Window manager that Windows uses doesn't provide this functionality, the only closest thing could be WinKey+Shift+ArrowKeys which moves the window to the other display. Maybe [PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys) has that? If not, open an issue on the GitHub describing your problem and maybe someone lends a hand. Good luck.

Comment: @oxou thanks for the reply!